# accessing 2d vector using enums as indices

Tags: c++, vector, enums

I want to access a 2-D vector using enums as indices. This however gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I created the enums as follows -

```
enum ROW 
{
    R0 = 0,
    R1 = 1,
};

ROW row; 

enum COLUMN 
{
    C1 = 0,
    C2 = 1,
}; 

COLUMN col;
```

The 2-D vector is created like this -

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> alpha{ { 1.46774172175387E-005, 2.000064981},
                                        { 3.46774172175387E-005, 4.59485786231327E-005} };
```

I get the error when I try to access the elements like this -

```
p = alpha[row][col];
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

I work on Xcode 6.1, OS X Yosemite.

Comment: well enums shouldn't be treated as integer first of all, as the enum specification have changed in c++ 11, they have been modified to enum classes..however if you still want to use them...no issues...row and col are objects to enum, you should use specific subuscript

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you haven't *initialised* `row`, or `col`.  If so, then the behaviour of `p = alpha[row][col];` will be *undefined*.

Note that it is possible to assign other integral values to `row`, and `col` beyond the ones specified explicitly in the `enum`. So your approach will not necessarily prevent access attempts outside the array bounds.

C++11 introduces enumerator classes which have tighter rules.

Comment: How could you know that, by the code, the thread creator has shown so far?!? You don't even see the declaration of those variables. Maybe they are initialized during declaration. The thread creator has to show more code to us!

Comment: I'd almost bet my career on the fact that at least one of `row`, or `col` are not initialised. Assuming automatic initialisation to 0 is a common mistake. If it turns out I'm incorrect then I'll downvote my own answer.

Comment: Could also be a for loop, which runs too far ... sth. like for(int row=0; row<=2; ++row)

Comment: I have initialised row to R0 and col to C1.

Comment: In which case my hunch was wrong. Please paste up an sscce.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the enum like this for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

enum ROW 
{
    R0 = 0,
    R1 = 1
};


enum COLUMN 
{
    C1 = 0,
    C2 = 1
}; 


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> alpha{ { 1.46774172175387E-005, 2.000064981},
                                        { 3.46774172175387E-005, 4.59485786231327E-005} };
    // Either like this:                                     
    std::cout << alpha[ROW::R0][COLUMN::C1];
    // Or simply like this:
    std::cout << alpha[R0][C1];
    return 0;
}
```

[Working example!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a4c2abc145936cd)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the enum variables see the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


enum ROW 
{
    R0 = 0,
    R1 = 1,
};


enum COLUMN 
{
    C1 = 0,
    C2 = 1,
}; 


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> alpha { { 1.46774172175387E-005, 2.000064981},
                                         { 3.46774172175387E-005, 4.59485786231327E-005} };
    ROW row = R0;
    COLUMN column = C2;
    double p = alpha[row][column];
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2.00006
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/dIRYoh

You can also use the enum values direct:

```
 double p = alpha[R0][C2];
```